# Data not displayed while it is in the table

Tags: php, sql

i'm currently creating a search engine using javascript *(for real time search)* and php (to link to the database). Actualy, my query works fine, the only problem is that he doesn't displayed the info of the other table *(see my code/explantions below)*.

```php
$search_val = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search_term']);
if(isset($search_val))
{
  if (empty($search_val)) {
    echo "";
    exit();
  }
  // $sql = "(SELECT 'steam' as identifier, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR lastname LIKE '%$search_val%') UNION (SELECT 'receiver' as identifier, date, content FROM bills WHERE date LIKE '%$search_val%' OR content LIKE '%$search_val%')
  // $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN bills ON users.steam = bills.receiver WHERE (users.firstname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR users.lastname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.date LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.content LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.amount LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.id LIKE '%$search_val%')";
  $nRows = $vlife->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users LEFT JOIN bills ON CONCAT(users.firstname, users.lastname) = bills.receiver
  WHERE (users.firstname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR CONCAT(users.firstname,' ',users.lastname) LIKE '%$search_val%'
  OR users.lastname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.date LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.content LIKE '%$search_val%'
  OR bills.amount LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.id LIKE '%$search_val%')")->fetchColumn();
  if ($nRows == 0) {
    echo "<div class='center'>La base de données ne contient aucuns <span style='font-weight:700;'>".$search_val."</span></div>";
    exit();
  } else {
    echo '<div class="center">Il y a  <span style="font-weight:700;">$nRows "$search_val"</span> dans la base de données</div>';
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN bills ON CONCAT(users.firstname, users.lastname) = bills.receiver
  WHERE (users.firstname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR CONCAT(users.firstname,' ',users.lastname) LIKE '%$search_val%'
  OR users.lastname LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.date LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.content LIKE '%$search_val%'
  OR bills.amount LIKE '%$search_val%' OR bills.id LIKE '%$search_val%')";
  $statement = $vlife->query($sql);
  while ($data = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo "<div class='row'>";
      echo "<div class='col s12 m4 l3'>";
        echo "<div class='center'><img src='https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/user-logo-png-3.png' alt='id' style='width:90%;'></div>";
        echo "<h5 class='".$col." black uppercase' style='font-weight:500;padding-left:10px;font-size:28px;'><i class='fas fa-user'></i> Identité</h5>";
        echo "<h6 class='uppercase $txtcol' style='font-weight:700'>Nom</h6>";
        echo $data['lastname'];
        echo "<h6 class='uppercase $txtcol' style='font-weight:700'>Prénom</h6>";
        echo $data['firstname'];
        echo "<h6 class='uppercase $txtcol' style='font-weight:700'>Age</h6>";
        echo $data['year']."ans";
        echo "<h6 class='uppercase $txtcol' style='font-weight:700'>Adresse</h6>";
        echo $data['adress'].".";
        echo "<hr/>";
        echo "<a class='$col waves-effect waves-light black-text btn'>button</a>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "<div class='col s12 m8 l9'>";
        echo "<h5 class='".$col." black uppercase' style='font-weight:500;padding-left:10px;font-size:28px;'><i class='fas fa-bookmark'></i> Casier Judicaire</h5>";
        echo $data['date']."<br>";
        echo $data['content']."<br>";
        echo $data['amount']."$<br>";
      echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<hr>";

    // I will have to change that i know :)
  }
  $statement->closeCursor();
  exit();
}
```

My "users" table:[image: users table content]

My "bills" table: [image: bills table content]

The results: [image: results]

As you can see, this part doesn't show:

```php
echo $data['date']."<br>";
echo $data['content']."<br>";
echo $data['amount']."$<br>";
```

Any ideas ?

*PS: I know that the problem comes from the SQL but i don't know what to do, i tried many things like UNION (ALL) (display more that expected) and LEFT JOIN (doesn't display everything)*

Comment: If you know that the problem comes from the SQL, why are you showing us all that other stuff? Make it easy to assist you - [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have an error in your query.. specifically, on the `ON` of the `LEFT JOIN`, look at it:

```
FROM users LEFT JOIN bills ON CONCAT(users.firstname, users.lastname) = bills.receiver
```

If you concat two strings such as uh, "Red" and "John" the result will obviously be "RedJohn" while in `bills.receiver` you have a space between the two strings.

You need to concat with also a space between firstname and lastname for the join (as you do in the where) to find something on the right table.

Also, I suggest you to try the query directly from a sql client to check, makes things more easy to fix on the fly while you experiment.

Edit:

Also, if you look at your where, check this:

```
WHERE (users.firstname LIKE '%$search_val%' 
    OR CONCAT(users.firstname,' ',users.lastname) LIKE '%$search_val%'
    OR users.lastname LIKE '%$search_val%'
```

Can't you just check using the concat expression? The other two are redundant, since you use a `LIKE`